# JavaScript itareate over divs and create a new one if doesn't fits

Tags: javascript

Hello guys I hope you can help me with JavaScript, I'm trying to itarate over some divs, the issue is that when I iterate sometimes a div never change to the other divs, it suppose to be infinite, I will recive thousands of different divs with different height and it should create an other div container in the case it does not fits but I can not achieve it work's, I'm using Vanilla JavaScript because I'm lerning JavaScript Regards.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
    .big_container{
    height: 600px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    float: left;
    }
    .items{
    background-color: gray;
    height: 50px;
    }
    .new_container{
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    height: 300px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5px;

    }


    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="big_container">
        <div class="items">1</div>
        <div class="items">2</div>
        <div class="items">3</div>
        <div class="items">4</div>
        <div class="items">5</div>
        <div class="items">6</div>
        <div class="items">7</div>
        <div class="items">8</div>
        <div class="items">9</div>
        <div class="items">10</div>
        <div class="items">11</div>
        <div class="items">12</div>             
        <div class="items">13</div>             



    </div>

    <div class="new_container">


    </div>




</body>
<script>

number = 0
sum = 0

new_container = document.getElementsByClassName('new_container')[number].offsetHeight

divs = document.getElementsByClassName('items')
for ( var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++ ){
sum += this.document.getElementsByClassName( 'items' )[0].offsetHeight


if ( sum <= new_container ){
console.log(sum, "yes")

document.getElementsByClassName("new_container")[number].appendChild( this.document.getElementsByClassName( 'items' )[0] )

} else {

sum = 0
console.log(sum, "NO entra")
nuevo_contenedor = document.createElement('div'); // Creo un contenedor
nuevo_contenedor.className = "new_container";
nuevo_contenedor.setAttribute("style", "background-color: red;");
document.body.appendChild(nuevo_contenedor)
number += + 1   
}




}


</script>
</html>
```

I really apreciate a hand.

Comment: I do not quite understand your problem. Write down the items you need to do and I will help you.

Comment: Thank you Senenko I have a big container with 13 divs enside, let's suppose they could be 500 or 40 the issue is that all those divs have different text so they have different height, now what I'm trying to do is to iterate each one and put each one in new_container div, let suppose they are 500, in this case new_container has 300px height so it should put all the divs fits in this container then, make an other one and an other one and an other one ultil it finish to iterate. if you see the coude it works with the first div ( the fisrt if ) but not with the second one.

Comment: Problem solved, Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I know that I'm late, but there is my approach how this can be done.

```js
// generate items with different height
function generateItems(count) {
  const arr = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    const div = document.createElement("DIV");
    const height = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 10);
    div.setAttribute("style", `height: ${height}px`);
    div.setAttribute("class", "items");

    const t = document.createTextNode(i + 1);
    div.appendChild(t);
    arr.push(div);
  }

  return arr;
}

function createNewContainer(height) {
  const new_container = document.createElement("DIV")
  new_container.setAttribute("class", "new_container");
  new_container.setAttribute("style", `height: ${height}px`)

  document.body.appendChild(new_container);

  return new_container;
}

function breakFrom(sourceContainerId, newContainerHeight) {
  const srcContainer = document.getElementById(sourceContainerId);
  const items = srcContainer.childNodes;

  let new_container = createNewContainer(newContainerHeight);
  let sumHeight = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    let item = items[i];

    if (item.offsetHeight > newContainerHeight) {
      // stop!!! this item too big to fill into new container
      throw new Error("Item too big.");
    }

    if (sumHeight + item.offsetHeight < newContainerHeight) {
      // add item to new container
      sumHeight += item.offsetHeight;
      new_container.appendChild(item.cloneNode(true));
    } else {
      // create new container
      new_container = createNewContainer(newContainerHeight);
      new_container.appendChild(item.cloneNode(true));

      // don't forget to set sumHeight)
      sumHeight = item.offsetHeight;
    }
  }

  // if you want to remove items from big_container
  // for (let i = items.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  //   srcContainer.removeChild(items[i]);
  // }
}

// create big container with divs
const big_container = document.getElementById("big_container");
const items = generateItems(13);
items.forEach((div, index) => {
  big_container.appendChild(div);
});

breakFrom("big_container", 300);
```

```css
#big_container {
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  float: left;
}

.items {
  background-color: gray;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  text-align: center;
}

.new_container {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="big_container"></div>
```

This example gives you the ability to play with divs of random height. Hope, this will help you.